# using javascript with TreeView nodes Check/Uncheck Functionality

Tags: javascript, asp.net, treeview

i'm using following javascript with TreeView nodes checkboxes Check/Uncheck Functionality.I have three levels in the treeview.parent,child and siblings.javascript code works fine but i need the siblings level to be checked and unchecked interdependently.with out affecting parent and child check/uncheck.can some one plz help me to modify the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function OnTreeClick(evt) {
            var src = window.event != window.undefined ? window.event.srcElement : evt.target
            var isChkBoxClick = (src.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input" && src.type == "checkbox");
            if (isChkBoxClick) {
                var parentTable = GetParentByTagName("table", src);
                var nxtSibling = parentTable.nextSibling;
                if (nxtSibling && nxtSibling.nodeType == 1)//check if nxt sibling is not null & is an element node
                {
                    if (nxtSibling.tagName.toLowerCase() == "div") //if node has children
                    {
                        //check or uncheck children at all levels
                        CheckUncheckChildren(parentTable.nextSibling, src.checked);
                    }
                }
                //check or uncheck parents at all levels
                CheckUncheckParents(src, src.checked);
            }
        }

        function CheckUncheckChildren(childContainer, check) {
            var childChkBoxes = childContainer.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var childChkBoxCount = childChkBoxes.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < childChkBoxCount; i++) {
                childChkBoxes[i].checked = check;
            }
        }

        function CheckUncheckParents(srcChild, check) {
            var parentDiv = GetParentByTagName("div", srcChild);
            var parentNodeTable = parentDiv.previousSibling;

            if (parentNodeTable) {
                var checkUncheckSwitch;

                if (check) //checkbox checked
                {
                    checkUncheckSwitch = true;
                }
                else //checkbox unchecked
                {
                    var isAllSiblingsUnChecked = AreAllSiblingsUnChecked(srcChild);
                    if (!isAllSiblingsUnChecked)
                        checkUncheckSwitch = true;
                    else
                        checkUncheckSwitch = false;
                }

                var inpElemsInParentTable = parentNodeTable.getElementsByTagName("input");
                if (inpElemsInParentTable.length > 0) {
                    var parentNodeChkBox = inpElemsInParentTable[0];
                    parentNodeChkBox.checked = checkUncheckSwitch;
                    //do the same recursively
                    CheckUncheckParents(parentNodeChkBox, checkUncheckSwitch);
                }
            }
        }

        function AreAllSiblingsUnChecked(chkBox) {
            var parentDiv = GetParentByTagName("div", chkBox);
            var childCount = parentDiv.childNodes.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                if (parentDiv.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) //check if the child node is an element node
                {
                    if (parentDiv.childNodes[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == "table") {
                        var prevChkBox = parentDiv.childNodes[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
                        //if any of sibling nodes are not checked, return false
                        if (prevChkBox.checked) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        //utility function to get the container of an element by tagname
        function GetParentByTagName(parentTagName, childElementObj) {
            var parent = childElementObj.parentNode;
            while (parent.tagName.toLowerCase() != parentTagName.toLowerCase()) {
                parent = parent.parentNode;
            }
            return parent;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// trvTest.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OnCheckBoxCheckChanged(event)"); 

function OnCheckBoxCheckChanged(event)
        {
            var obj = window.event.srcElement;
            var treeNodeFound = false;
            var checkedState;
            if (obj.tagName == "INPUT" && obj.type == "checkbox") 
            {
                var treeNode = obj;
                checkedState = treeNode.checked;
                do
                {
                    obj = obj.parentElement;
                } 

                while (obj.tagName != "TABLE")
                var parentTreeLevel = obj.rows[0].cells.length;
                var parentTreeNode = obj.rows[0].cells[0];
                var tables = obj.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
                var numTables = tables.length
                if (numTables >= 1)
                {
                    for (i=0; i < numTables; i++)
                    {
                        if (tables[i] == obj)
                        {
                            treeNodeFound = true;
                            i++;
                            if (i == numTables)
                            {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        if (treeNodeFound == true)
                        {
                            var childTreeLevel = tables[i].rows[0].cells.length;
                            if (childTreeLevel > parentTreeLevel)
                            {
                                var cell = tables[i].rows[0].cells[childTreeLevel - 1];
                                var inputs = cell.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
                                if (inputs.length > 0)
                                    inputs[0].checked = checkedState;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```